# Common functions used by several projects, best way to share them on git repositories

Tags: git

I have a folder, some_dir/mylib/myfuncs/ contains several .py file that I would like to import for a lot of projects and I add .some_dir/mylib to PYTHONPATH so I can import them for all projects.

Now, the problem is that I have to share my projects on github with my team members. So I create a repository called on mylib and told my teammates to download this too for which and which projects.

Is there any better solutions than this?

Is it possible for me to put part of the mylib files in one specific project and sync the change I have done during this project to the file in folder of mylib

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new repository for your library files. Then you can add that repository as a submodule to every new project that needs it. That way you can easily update/change you library files as a separate project.

You can read more about submodules and how they work [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: thanks a lot, this method works well. Though someone down voted my post, ;(

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to employ one of several strategies:

- [subtrees](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-subtrees-943d29a798ec#.kf1xck1dm)
- [submodules](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-submodules-34c65e940407#.r3h5rrler)
- Package managers can automate builds and dependency management (e.g. [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) for Python) and allow you to create semantic versioning schemes.
- [GitHub releases](https://help.github.com/articles/about-releases/) let you package your software for download (includes binaries).